# :conditions deprecated in Rails 4, need new Polymorphic syntax for accessing parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a fairly normal class structure, using a polymorphic association:

```rb
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :opportunities, :as => :has_opportunities, dependent: :destroy
end 

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :opportunities, :as => :has_opportunities, dependent: :destroy
end 

class Opportunity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :has_opportunities, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :contact, foreign_key: 'has_opportunities_id', conditions: "opportunities.has_opportunities_type = 'Contact'"
  belongs_to :company, foreign_key: 'has_opportunities_id', conditions: "opportunities.has_opportunities_type = 'Company'"
end
```

In Rails 4 using :conditions has been deprecated, but I can't figure out the "new" syntax required to allow access to the parent object from the child.

Edit: Yes, you can do  opportunity.has_opportunities which will return you a Contact or a Company, but it is often "nicer" in code to use opportunity.contact or opportunity.company

Comment: a side question, conditions on belongs_to are supposed to be on the association not the model itself. so how does this work? I tried on a model I have and it gives me an error that column name not found.

Comment: IT will work with the bit I missed out for brevity ... editing it now ...

Comment: belongs_to :has_opportunities, polymorphic: true

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply set it up as a regular polymorphic association?

```
class Opportunity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :has_opportunities, polymorphic: true
end
```

Comment: Sorry, that's already in there (snipped for brevity) ... and can use Opportunity.has_opportunities to get the parent ... it's just "nicer" to have: if Opportunity.contact etc etc